# Solve the recurrence relation using iterative substitution

Tags: combinatorics

$a_n = a_{n/2} + n^2 + 1, a_1 = 1, a_2 = 6, a_4 = 23, a_8 = 88$. 
This was an exam question, and for some reason when I tried to do this problem with iterative substitution, I kept getting the wrong solution to the recurrence relation, but I was pretty confident it was $a_n = a_1 + ... + log_2n$, where in the ellipses I would fill in the sum of $2^2 + 4^2 + 8^2 + ... + (\frac n8)^2 + (\frac n4)^2 + (\frac n2)^2+ n^2$, which I converted to $4 + 4^2 + 4^3 + ... + 4^{log_2n}$, which should be a geometric progression, missing the first term, of sum equaling $\frac {1 - 4^{log_2n - 1 + 1}}{1 - 4} - 1 = \frac{1 - 4^{log_2n}}{-3} - 1$, but using that, the recurrence relation did not give the correct $a_n$'s, but then I tried strategically random stuff on my calculator, and arrived at the solution of the recurrence relation being $a_n = \frac{1 - 4^{log_22n}}{-3} + log_22n - 1$. Somehow, this works for the first few $a_n$'s I listed. But, does it work for all, and if so, how? Furthermore, what answer should I have gotten with the iterative substitution method? Thank you. P.S. My first post!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you type `\log` in order to get $\log$.

Comment: I don’t understand, what would $a_3$ be for example?

Comment: It looks like you added up the added up the $n^2$s, but not the $1$s.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: That's the $\log_2n$ term (easy to miss since it's still in the wrong font).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that it's just a typo that the term $\left(\frac n2\right)^2$ is missing in your sum.

If you substitute $n=2$ in your result, you get $0$ even though the sum in this case should be $4$. There's no reason to subtract $1$ in the exponent; the sum should be

$$
\frac{1-4^{1+\log_2n}}{1-4}-1\;.
$$

If you add $a_1=1$ (which you could have included in the geometric series instead of subtracting $1$) and $\log_2 n$, you get

$$
\frac{1-4^{1+\log_2n}}{1-4}+\log_2n\;,
$$

which is equal to your other result since $\log_22n=1+\log_2n$.

Comment: I see, so, this means the geometric progression with x = 4, go up to 4^(log base 2 of n) instead of ((log base 2 of n) - 1), right?

Comment: @Ryusei: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I should have realized that (log base 2 of n) + 1 = log base 2 of 2n. How shameful.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are only interested in $a_n$ with $n$ a power of $2$. This is a rather perverse notion of a sequence. I'll find it more comfortable to set $b_k=a_{2^k}$ so that the recurrence becomes $b_0=1$ and $b_k=b_{k-1}+4^k+1$.
Then
$$b_k=1+\sum_{j=1}^k(4^j+1)=k+1+\frac{4^{k+1}-4}3=k+\frac{4^{k+1}-1}3.$$
When $n=2^k$ is a power of $2$, then
$$b_n=\log_2n+\frac{4n^2-1}3.$$